# Checking if a solution is correct in another model in ILOG CPLEX

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, constraint, cplex, constraint-programming

I've made two model that are supposed to represent the same thing but written in two different way in IBM ILOG CPLEX (one in CP and the other in MILP with CPLEX).

They give me different optimal value (both with optimal gap of 0) so I would like to know which constraint is not respected in one of the model

They both output solution in the following way :

```
alpha = [0 16 23 54 78];
beta = [1 0 1 0 0 0 0];
...
```

both models share almost all variables name (except for some intermediate variables that i had to create in the MILP)

So I would like to give the outputs values of a model as inputs for the other model to know what are the constraint that are not respected with that values.

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: A simple method is to add constraints of the form x_j = f_j i.e. you fix variable x_j to the known value f_j. If for instance, the model with the fixings included is infeasible, then your hypothesis about the fixings are wrong.

Comment: Extending Erling's comment, I would take the solution with the better objective value and fix it in the other model, then look for which constraints it violates. If the better solution is actually feasible in the other model, then things get tricky -- you have to try to figure out why the solver of that model never found it.

Comment: Btw during this test it might be a good idea to set the relative and absolute duality gaps to (near) zero.